# Problems with unixODBC and FreeTDS config

Tags: centos, freetds, unixodbc

I have been working on this for way too long and can't seem to figure it out. I am sure I have something wrong in my freetds.conf, odbc.ini or odbcinst.ini. I can connect to my mssql 2008 server using tsql, but still can't with isql or of course through php.

I am on CentOS 5.6.

Can anyone offer some assistance?

Thanks!
Shawn

This is in my sqltrace.log:

```
 [ODBC][12249][1347850711.939084][__handles.c][459]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
    Environment = 0x1b5fc6c0
    [ODBC][12249][1347850711.939149][SQLAllocHandle.c][375]
    Entry:
        Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x1b5fc6c0
[ODBC][12249][1347850711.939187][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Output Handle = 0x1b5fcff0
[ODBC][12249][1347850711.939231][SQLConnect.c][3654]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x1b5fcff0
            Server Name = [MSSQL_DSN][length = 9 (SQL_NTS)]
            User Name = [InetIndyArtsRemote][length = 18 (SQL_NTS)]
            Authentication = [**********][length = 10 (SQL_NTS)]
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

        DIAG [01000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unexpected EOF from the server

        DIAG [01000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed

        DIAG [S1000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source

[ODBC][12249][1347850711.949640][SQLConnect.c][4021]
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
[ODBC][12249][1347850711.949694][SQLFreeHandle.c][286]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x1b5fcff0
[ODBC][12249][1347850711.949735][SQLFreeHandle.c][337]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][12249][1347850711.949773][SQLFreeHandle.c][219]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 1
            Input Handle = 0x1b5fc6c0
```

freetds.conf:

```
    #   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
    #
    # This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same
    # name is found in the installation directory.
    #
    # For information about the layout of this file and its settings,
    # see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".

    # Global settings are overridden by those in a database
    # server specific section
    [global]
            # TDS protocol version
            tds version = 8.0

            # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
            # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
            dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
            debug flags = 0xffff
            dump file append = yes

            # Command and connection timeouts
    ;       timeout = 10
    ;       connect timeout = 10

            # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
            # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
            # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
            text size = 64512

[IndyArtsDB]
        host = xxx.xx.xxx.xx
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
```

ODBC.INI

```
[MSSQL_DSN]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=IndyArts DB on Rackspace
Trace=No
Server=xxx.xx.xxx.xx
Port=1433
Database=DBName
```

ODCBINST.INI

```
[ODBC]
DEBUG=1
TraceFile=/home/ftp/sqltrace.log
Trace=Yes

[FreeTDS]
Description=MSSQL Driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your sqltrace.log it looks to me like an authentication error - you get that "Unexpected EOF from the server" message immediately after authenticating...

Is there any chance the remote server is blocking connections from your CentOS server, either completely or on port 1433?  Any chance the "client charset = UTF-8" in your freetds.conf is causing the problem?

This is my (working) setup on an Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) machine.

Here is my /etc/odbc.ini file:

```
[xyz]
Description             = XYZ Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = MyDB
ServerName              = xyz
TDS_Version             = 8.0
```

And my /etc/odbcinst.ini file:

```
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver          = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
```

And finally my /etc/freetds/freetds.conf file:

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
        text size = 64512

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
        host = symachine.domain.com
        port = 5000
        tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
        host = ntmachine.domain.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0

# The XYZ database
[xyz]
        host = XYZ
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
```

Comment: This comment came up in search results and was really helpful in resolving a similar problem.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the version numbers in FreeTDS have been changed from 8.0 to 7.1 and 9.0 to 7.2.
See http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm